# Problems installing and opening Anaconda3 on macOS Sierra

Tags: anaconda, conda

I am using a MacBook Pro (early-2011) with macOS Sierra v10.12.6. I can not install and run Anaconda3. I have downloaded the pkg file from the Anaconda webpage. First day, it took overnight to finish installing. After which it said installation failed. I tried to delete all files and reinstall all over again serval times, but this hasn't worked. I made sure the /opt folder was empty before I reinstall again, but even like that didn't work.

Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: You could try the command line installer and post any error message you get here

Answer (score 1):

Had a similiar problem with a geriatric iMac mid 2010 running OSX 10.13.16. The GUI installer for Anaconda 3 takes an age, then reports there was a problem.

I downloaded the install script and ran, "bash Anaconda3-2022.05-MacOSX-x86_64.sh" in a terminal.

Answered questions, and after some time, have Anaconda installed in my personal space. Now to figure out how to use the latest LTS Julia.

Answer (score 0):

**No Anaconda support.** Current Anaconda (and likely Miniconda) distribution [declares a minimum system requirement](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/) of **macOS v10.13+**. One could try scraping back through the archive to find an older distribution that will install, but I wouldn't recommend that.

**Conda Forge supports macOS 10.9+.** Conda Forge still builds all **osx-64** packages [with a macOS 10.9 target](https://github.com/conda-forge/conda-forge-pinning-feedstock/blob/0d0834af536a7ae31a6a0e95fbd0610d5d99c27f/recipe/conda_build_config.yaml#L113). Hence, you should be fine using instead [a Miniforge variant](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#miniforge) for the **base** Conda installation. I strongly recommend [Mambaforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#mambaforge), and using `mamba` instead of `conda`.